# animation through css3 transition

Tags: flash, html, css, css-transitions

I need to create an animation which is trigerred when the cursor hovers over it. The animation is an acronym which expands to its full form, eg when I hover over "CSS3" . it should expand to "cascading style sheet" with ascading appearing in between the letters "C" and "S" with the letters coming one after the other will it be possible only through CSS3? *(Editor notes, I presume he means, like the new letters are typed, rather then just appear all at once)*

Comment: I have edited (but waiting for it to be accepted) saying that I assume you mean you want to new letters to look like they are being typed in one at a time rather then appearing all at once

Comment: Also, are you really using flash for this? or is it as I suspect actually just HTML with CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can most probably do this with CSS 3.

Here is a hint I made:

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TyANu/3/) (Hover over the word CSS to see the effect)

This can be made with some classes and just spans.
For simplicity I did just use a P-Tag and Span's inside.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Try setting the speed of the animation to get a different effect.
You should also be able to set different timings for the effects (color, text-indent) so the font gets visible when the text-indent has finished

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do, then this can not be done through CSS, other then perhaps a lot of ridiculous rules.

If you are using flash, then just use a movie clip and a bit of Action Script to trigger the animation.

However, I believe you are actually using HTML/CSS/JS (web browser stuff) in which case, you will need to make use of some JavaScript. I suggest you look at Jquery, a nice library that will make it very easy to detect the hover effect and then manipulate what it says.

You will probably need something like...

```
<span class="ExpandingAbreviation">
    <span class="short">CSS3</span>
    <span class="Long">cascading style shet</span>
</span>
```

Then in you style sheet, make Long hidden, and through Jquery, you will need to set up a listener for hover events on 'short' and write the code to hide that and reveal long. Though, I am not too sure exactly what effect you are after

Answer (score 0):

The Same can be done by changing the InnerHTML value onMouseover() in Js.

```
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>
function changetext()
{
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<p>Cascading Style Sheets<p>'
}
</script>
<div id="change" onmouseover="changetext();">css</div>
</body>
```

But i don't think it is possible to change text in css3. We can add transition effects to look good.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.designscripting.com/webtools/css3/generator/

CSS3 transition generator.

Answer (score -1):

I have built a jsfiddle, which does what you like. I think it's the easiest way to understand what is going on. All you need for that functionality is jQuery. Just click on the "CSS" to try it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/njZXj/5/